# Eclipse running my own configuration in debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created my own launch configuration in eclipse to run a java program. Now what I need is to debug the java program using my own launch configuration that I have already created. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Your Launch configuration should appear in the Debug Configurations menu as well as the Run Configurations, just run it from the Debug config.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
Run -> Debug Configurations

Find your debug configuration under Java Application and click on debug(right bottom corner)

if you need to add arguments then click on Arguments tab and under Program Arguments add your input parameters

If you want to import your launch configuration in eclipse then:
File --> Import --> Launch Configurations --> select your launch configuration from disk

Comment: I think I need to look for "debugging a plug-in project in eclipse"

Comment: no you don't need just follow the steps and put comment if you struggle somewhere